# How to show custom data of custom page event in the experience profile instead of current page url while tracking external links using FXM?

Tags: xdb, xconnect, experience-analytics, experience-profile, fxm

We are using FXM to track the clicks on the external links and the data is stored in the xdb Shard Interactions table > Event Column but in the experience profile, the url shows the curent item page where the link was clicked.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any pipeline to intercept and send the external href as current item url so experience profile shows external link for custom page events.
2. Is there any way we can show the number of clicks for each of these external links in analytics dashboard?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look in `/App_Config/Sitecore/FederatedExperienceManager/Sitecore.FXM.config` you can see all of the processors that are called for <tracking.triggerpageevent>

```
          <tracking.triggerpageevent>
            <!-- Run when a page event is triggered by the client javascript to record the event in the DMS in the current session. -->
            <processor type="Sitecore.FXM.Pipelines.Tracking.TriggerPageEvent.RunInitializeTrackingContextProcessor, Sitecore.FXM" resolve="true" />
            <processor type="Sitecore.FXM.Pipelines.Tracking.TriggerPageEvent.ResolveCurrentPageContext, Sitecore.FXM" />
            <processor type="Sitecore.FXM.Pipelines.Tracking.TriggerPageEvent.TriggerEventsProcessor, Sitecore.FXM" resolve="true" />
            <processor type="Sitecore.FXM.Pipelines.Tracking.AfterEvent.CleanupAnalyticsCookieInResponseProcessor, Sitecore.FXM" resolve="true" />
          </tracking.triggerpageevent>
```

You could create your own custom processor which extends sitecore's TriggerEventProcessor and overwrite the TriggerPageEvent. Use dotpeek for example to see the existing implementation of Sitecore.FXM.Pipelines.Tracking.TriggerPageEvent.TriggerEventsProcessor. Make sure to also register the custom processor class in the config file by using patching.

A similar approach can be seen for an older sitecore version https://reyrahadian.com/2016/07/26/sitecore-8-how-to-update-contact-through-fxm-api/